# getting an average of values from dictionaries with keys with a list of values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

For my final python assignment at my university I need to create functions within Jupyter Notebook to conduct a small research. I need to create dictionaries and lists from .csv files and build functions for the dictionaries that I get from my read_csv() function. For this assignment I am allowed to ask and google because the functions I have to make are fairly common problems people walk into.

The way these dictionaries look like after my read_csv() returns them is as follows:

```
data_dict = { "abc" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
              "def" : [4, 5, 6, 7],
              "ghi" : [8, 9, 10, 11]
            }
```

So basically a dictionary with a large amount of keys with each a list of values. What I need to do is sum up all the numbers of the first index of each list and get the average from the sum, then the second index, third index and so on, returning a list of all averages. With the result being something like:

```
averages = [4.333, 5.333, 6.333, 7.333]
```

How would one go about this without importing anything? In the past weeks we haven't really talked about working with dictionaries and I've tried looking for solutions on the internet but couldn't find any dealing with summing up integers or floats at specific indexes from different lists.

Comment: Also, consider using `data_dict.values()`

Comment: Why no imports?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham homework assignment

Comment: @jcfollower Thank you very much, `.values()` s indeed helps a lot getting a better grip on how to work with dictionaries and their values.

Answer (score 2):

First collect the values, transpose them and then its easy:

```
# values of the dict
values = data_dict.values()

# transposed average
averages = [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in zip(*values)]
print (averages)
```

returns:

```
[4.333333333333333, 5.333333333333333, 6.333333333333333, 7.333333333333333]
```

A shorter *'less-explanatory'* one-liner would be:

```
averages = [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in zip(*data_dict.values())]
```

Comment: What are you calling list?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `list`, it's not necessary.

Comment: Also sum takes a start value  so all you need is `sum(x, 0.0) / len(x)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, working with a list of lists is a lot easier than working within a dictionary for me. Your suggestion has helped me a lot to understand dictionaries more and figure out what to do with my function.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` the values to get the columns, and divide each column's `sum` by its `len`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

```
data_dict = { "abc" : [1, 2, 3, 4],
              "def" : [4, 5, 6, 7],
              "ghi" : [8, 9, 10, 11]
            }
l1 = data_dict.values()
l2 = []
for i in zip(*l1):
    l2.append(float(sum(i)) / float(len(i)))
print l2
```